# Yii 2 Advanced Template url

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've installed advanced template on my local system but I can't seem to figure out the url, or the url is not working?
Advanced template is installed under advanced directory.

None of following works

http://localhost/yii/advanced/

http://localhost/yii/advanced/web/

http://localhost/yii/advanced/web/index.php

http://localhost/yii/advanced/frontend/web/index.php

What is the url to access website after advanced template is installed? I can see all folders and files under /advanced. Is there any error with installation?

Following is the error I'm getting:

Not Found
The requested URL /web/index.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advance template consist of 3 diff apps `frontend`, `backend` and `console`. Where `console` is for the `Cli` and the rest for web, it isnt like basic-app, so you need to access it via `http://localhost/yii/advanced/frontend/web/index.php` or `http://localhost/yii/advanced/backend/web/index.php`

Comment: Not sure what I did but when I reinstalled in a fresh directory it worked. Tx for the help.